# Java Optional парсинг строкового представления числа, которое может быть пустой строкой

Tags: java

В коллекции MongoDB лежат документы, в которых есть строковое поле `guiltyDays`, которое содержит строковое представление чисел, но может быть пустой строкой.

Мне нужно парсить это поле и учитывать, что там может быть пустая строка. Я вышел из положения так:

```
int guiltyDays = 0;
try {
    Integer.parseInt(entry.getString("guiltyDays"));
} catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        System.out.println(e);
}
```

Хочу сделать код чище и использовать `Optional` и дефолтное значение в `.orElse(0)`. Как можно переписать этот код с использованием оптионалов?

Пытался написать так, но не получилось.

```
Optional<String> gd = Optional.ofNullable(entry.getString("guiltyDays"));
guiltyDays = gd.ifPresent(System.out::println);
```

Answer (score 2):

Optional не совсем подходит по 2 причинам :

1. ifPresent не позволит вам присвоить значение int в лямбде
   (guiltyDays должно быть финальным). Чтобы обойти это надо
   использовать обертку (AtomicInteger например)
2. Optional.ofNullable
       позволяет использовать нул, но не проверяет пустая ли строка.

Можно использовать такой вариант, если вы уверены, что строка пустая, а не нулловая приходит из базы:

```
    String s = entry.getString("guiltyDays");
    int guiltyDays = 0;
    if (!s.isEmpty()) {
        guiltyDays = Integer.parseInt(s);
    }
```

С Optional вариант выглядел бы так :

```
Integer guiltyDays = Optional.of(s)
        .filter(str -> !str.isEmpty())
        .map(Integer::parseInt)
        .orElse(0);
```

Comment: Спасибо. А в каких случаях нужен Optional? Есть в документе MongoDB есть поле типа массива, в котором может быть null, и в джаве тип этого поля List<Document>, можно ли использовать здесь optional?

Comment: Если пробрасываете лист дальше по методам и вместо null хотите использовать какое-нибудь дефолтное значение, то можно. Что-то вроде :
Optional.ofNullable(documents)
                .orElse(Collections.emptyList());